# Mocking an ObjectReader?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test, and the class I am testing gets passed a mocked ObjectMapper when being created... But then the code I am trying to test is a method which then creates an ObjectReader from that mapper (which is better practice than having mappers all over the file etc.

Now, I believe, what I probably need to do in my test... is have something that mocks a reader when it is being asked for... but I have no idea how I might do that...

I mock my mapper like this :

```
ObjectMapper mockMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
```

and then in the ACTUAL class which does the work normally, I create the reader as follows :

```
ObjectReader objectReader = mapper.reader(ObjectNode.class);
```

Now, I assume the problem here is that the mapper is mocked, so then when the code tries to create the reader, it is OBVIOUSLY going to be null.

so in my test, I know I probably need to do something like this :

```
when(mockMapper.reader(ObjectNode.class)).thenReturn(mock(ObjectReader(ObjectNode.class)));
```

but I know that is not right (because it doesn't work) - and I need a little guidance on getting it to work...

All help is appreciated here. Thanks!

Comment: Care to explain the meaning of `it doesn't work` ? Also, what you want to assert in your test?

Comment: I did, I said the reader is obviously going to be null...

Comment: [1] Ensure your `when(...).thenReturn(...)` has been called prior to executing `mapper.reader(...)`. [2] Put a breakpoint on `ObjectReader objectReader = mapper.reader(ObjectNode.class);` line, inspect the `mapper` value, ensure it's a mock object.

Answer (score 0):

If you could edit your question to include your code under test, that would make question more clear. I am trying to answer with what I understand from your question.
You can create real object of ObjectReader class or you can mock as

```
ObjectReader objectReader = mock(ObjectReader.class);
```

Now use mockito to return ObjectReader class.

```
when(mockMapper.reader(any(ObjectNode.class))).thenReturn(objectReader));
```